# Is there a way to tell if a string/guid is used anywhere else in the code?

Tags: c#

Lets say i have a file full if guids and I want to check if they are already used somewhere in the code like this :

```
public static Guid GenericGuidName{ get { return new Guid("2b1bd512-6d75-4c63-9e2e-dfebda4f4393"); } }
```

Is there a way, other then ctrl+f-ing the entire  solution for every single guid ?

Comment: The question here is, why don't you just generate guids? The chance of getting a duplicate is near 0.

Comment: What IDE are you using ?

Comment: Do you want to it through coding?

Comment: I don't really care how its done. I'm using VS . I'm refactoring old and very large application and I want to find and remove all the guids that are in the database but are not in the code, and I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do it.My line of thought is that if i find every guid that is used and subtract it from every single guid in the databse i can find the ones that are redundant and remove them

Comment: 1) Create a regex matching a guid. 2) grep all source-files for matches to that regex to get a list of all GUIDs. 3) Look for duplicates within that list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all of the GUIDs are exposed using the code pattern you provided, you can find all of those GUIDs and put them in a dictionary, with a bit of Reflection.

```
class MysteryCode
{
    public static Guid Foo { get { return new Guid("2b1bd512-6d75-4c63-9e2e-dfebda4f4393"); } }
    public static Guid Bar { get { return new Guid("2b1bd512-6d75-4c63-9e2e-dfebda4f4394"); } }
}

public class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<Guid, PropertyInfo> FindGuids()
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .SelectMany
            (
                t => t.GetProperties
                (
                    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public
                )
            )
            .Where
            (
                p => p.PropertyType == typeof(Guid)
            )
            .ToDictionary
            (
                p => (Guid)p.GetValue(null),
                p => p
            );
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var dictionary = Program.FindGuids();

        foreach (var g in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}.{2}", g.Key, g.Value.DeclaringType.FullName, g.Value.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2b1bd512-6d75-4c63-9e2e-dfebda4f4393 Example.MysteryCode.Foo
2b1bd512-6d75-4c63-9e2e-dfebda4f4394 Example.MysteryCode.Bar
```

[Working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uMoLH6)